# I can not answer the native iOS confirm Detox - mocha application in React native

Tags: react-native, detox

I just started using Detox to test my react native app and I'm having some trouble to answer for native confirm.

I didnt find list of _UI......View 
(like: _UIAlertControllerActionView, _UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView)

```
it('should show world screen after tap', async () => {

    await loginPage.getFbBtn().tap();    
    // await element(by.type('_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView')).tap(); 
    //await element(by.text('Continue')).tap();
    await element(by.text('Continue').and(by.type('_UIAlertControllerActionView'))).tap();
  });
```

element(by.type('_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView')).tap();

(node:2009) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find UI element.
Exception with Action: {
  "Action Name":  "Tap",
  "Element Matcher":  "((!(kindOfClass('RCTScrollView')) && kindOfClass('(null)')) || (((kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) && parentThatMatches(kindOfClass('RCTScrollView'))) && ((kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) && parentThatMatches(kindOfClass('(null)')))))",
  "Recovery Suggestion":  "Check if the element exists in the UI hierarchy printed below. If it exists, adjust the matcher so that it accurately matches element."
}

Error Trace: [
  {
    "Description":  "Interaction cannot continue because the desired element was not found.",
    "Error Domain":  "com.google.earlgrey.ElementInteractionErrorDomain",
    "Error Code":  "0",
    "File Name":  "GREYElementInteraction.m",
    "Function Name":  "-[GREYElementInteraction matchedElementsWithTimeout:error:]",
    "Line":  "124"
  }
]

await element(by.text('Continue')).tap();

Error: Cannot find UI element.
Exception with Action: {
  "Action Name":  "Tap",
  "Element Matcher":  "((!(kindOfClass('RCTScrollView')) && (((kindOfClass('UILabel') || kindOfClass('UITextField') || kindOfClass('UITextView')) && hasText('Continue')) || (kindOfClass('RCTTextView') && an object with accessibilityLabel "Continue"))) || (((kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) && parentThatMatches(kindOfClass('RCTScrollView'))) && ((kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) && parentThatMatches((((kindOfClass('UILabel') || kindOfClass('UITextField') || kindOfClass('UITextView')) && hasText('Continue')) || (kindOfClass('RCTTextView') && an object with accessibilityLabel "Continue"))))))",
  "Recovery Suggestion":  "Check if the element exists in the UI hierarchy printed below. If it exists, adjust the matcher so that it accurately matches element."
}[image]

await element(by.text('Continue').and(by.type('_UIAlertControllerActionView'))).tap();
Error: Cannot find UI element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s not an alert you can interact with. That alert is rendered by a different process than your app, and Detox cannot interact with it. Instead, you should mock the API that shows this.